# How to interpret the result of ANOVA test on regression in R

Tags: r, regression, anova

Suppose I run a regression:

`alligator = data.frame(
  lnLength = c(3.87, 3.61, 4.33, 3.43, 3.81, 3.83, 3.46, 3.76,
    3.50, 3.58, 4.19, 3.78, 3.71, 3.73, 3.78),
  lnWeight = c(4.87, 3.93, 6.46, 3.33, 4.38, 4.70, 3.50, 4.50,
    3.58, 3.64, 5.90, 4.43, 4.38, 4.42, 4.25)
)
mylm <- lm (lnLength ~ lnWeight, data = alligator)`

then

`Anova (mylm, type = "III")`

Result:

```
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: lnLength
             Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 3.16147  1 2510.45 2.919e-16 ***
lnWeight    0.83847  1  665.81 1.495e-12 ***
Residuals   0.01637 13                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

How should I interpret the result of ANOVA? What does p-value mean?

The result of `mylm`:

```
summary (mylm)

Call:
lm(formula = lnLength ~ lnWeight, data = alligator)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.03714 -0.01994 -0.01175  0.01345  0.07003 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.49503    0.04980    50.1 2.92e-16 ***
lnWeight     0.28587    0.01108    25.8 1.49e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03549 on 13 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9808,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9794 
F-statistic: 665.8 on 1 and 13 DF,  p-value: 1.495e-12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use ANOVA to test the null hypothesis that the population mean is the same for all groups. You don't have different groups (or categories) here. You just have 1 continuous predictor and 1 continuous response, so don't worry about ANOVA at all.

For what it concerns the $p-$value of `lnWeight` in your regression summary, it's interpreted as saying that the probability $p$ that you could get an estimate $\hat{\beta_1}$ for the coefficient of `lnWeight` in absolute value larger than what you got (i.e., the probability that $|\hat{\beta_1}|>0.286$), **if the actual coefficient $\beta_1$ in the linear model is** 0 (*null hypothesis*), is $p=1.49e-12$, i.e., very small. It would then seem safe to reject the null...**however**, the computation of this $p-$value done by R relies on a series of assumptions, which you definitely should check with diagnostic plots before drawing any conclusions. Generating diagnostic plots for a linear model is immediate in R with `plot(mylm)`. However, *interpreting* them is another matter. You can learn more by searching this site for "linear model diagnostic plots", "check linear model assumptions" or something similar.

```
plot(mylm)
```

[image]

In your case there seem to be some issues. The residuals vs fitted plot (top left) shows that residuals are more often negative than positive (instead than being randomly spread above and below the $e=0$ line), but there are 3 quite large positive values. Also, the QQ plot (top left) seems to indicate that residuals are not normally distributed. With so few data it's hard to tell whether the population they're drawn from is really normal or not: a small size sample drawn from a normal distribution can look deceptively non-normal.

However, I think the problem is that you took the logs of both `Weight` and `Length` to obtain a linear model, the original model being (I guess) something like

$$\text{Length} \sim \alpha_0\text{Weight}^{\alpha_1} +\epsilon$$

The issue with this approach is that by taking logs, the error term $\epsilon$ which was originally normally distributed is transformed to an error term which is no more normally distributed, and this may be the reason why your residuals do not appear to be normally distributed. This means that inference with this model (confidence intervals for parameters estimates, $p-$values, etc.) may be unreliable. Now, you may object: "I'm really not interested in inference, I just want to use the model to make predictions". And by plotting your model and your data, you may think that it's not bad in that respect, as also suggested by the high adjusted $R^2$ in `mylm` summary:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(alligator, aes(x = lnLength, y = lnWeight)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

*However*, errors which are large on the original scale may look deceptively small on the log-scale. I think the safest/more accurate approach would be to use the coefficients from this linear model as starting points to fit a nonlinear model in the original variables. However, if you're not interested in inference and you don't care too much about the accuracy of your predictions, you could be satisfied with this model.

PS the definition of $p$-value I gave is specifically tailored to the case of simple (one predictor) linear regression. If you go to multivariate linear regression or even to GLMs, then by all means study the relevant topics instead than just relying on what I wrote for this specific example.